# Authorizing SQL statement execution

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

Is there a way we can authorize any sql statement to run only at particular databases/tables ?

We Know we can use multiple ways to implement authorization in API call, like JWT token. Is there a way provisioned by any RELATIONAL databse (MySQL, Postgress, etc) where we can authorize a sql statement to use only particular database /tables in the sql statement?

Sorry, i dont have any code to share it is more of a theoretical question.

Comment: Different user accounts with specific permissions assigned to them…?! https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/user-manag.html

Comment: First, MySQL and PostgreSQL are too different concerning permissions to put into a single question. Second, it is not quite clear what you want, and an example would be indicated. But it sounds like you let arbitrary users run arbitrary SQL statements against a database. This is a recipe for disaster.